# Certificado A3 no ASP.NET MVC e IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, iis

Tenho uma aplicação ASP.NET MVC4 e uso o código a seguir para ler o certificado A3(leitora ou pendrive) do usuário:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
  store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.MaxAllowed);

  var collection = store.Certificates;
  var fcollection = collection.Find(X509FindType.FindByTimeValid, DateTime.Now, true);
  var scollection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(fcollection, "Certificados válidos:", "Selecione o certificado que deseja usar",
            X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

Quanto estou debugando (usando o IISExpress) o código funciona normal, porém quando publico a aplicação no IIS 7.5 (na minha máquina local) retorna o seguinte erro:

> A sessão atual não é interativa.

Pergunta: É possível fazer o IIS "respeitar" o código á cima da mesma maneira que o IISExpress faz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> É possível fazer o IIS "respeitar" o código á cima da mesma maneira que o IISExpress faz?

Não. Isto não é um problema com o IIS. A questão é que você está usando um Certificado A3 (portanto, um Smart Card) para autenticação, ou ainda para assinar ou criptografar um objeto.

O problema aí é que essa extração de dados é sempre local, e o IIS só está local no momento em que você está desenvolvendo. Neste caso, é melhor desenvolver uma autenticação por Smart Card no seu sistema e usar o certificado dela para realizar as operações. [Este artigo é meio longo, mas explica tudo isso que eu falei](http://securitythroughabsurdity.com/2010/05/smart-card-authentication-module-update.html).

Ou, ainda, se você quer apenas extrair o certificado usando uma autenticação sua, pode escrever um componente ActiveX (que precisa ser instalado na máquina do usuário, portanto) e fazer este componente enviar os dados para a sua aplicação Web. [Aqui tem uma implementação](https://github.com/ubinity/webpcsc-firebreath). [Aqui tem outra](https://github.com/cardid/WebCard).

Comment: Cigano, o link do Activex (https://github.com/cardid/WebCard) que você postou seria ideal pra mim, porém não entendi como eu poderia passar um objeto tipo X509Certificate2UI. Você teria algum exemplo, se não for pedir muito.

Comment: [Já olhou aqui](http://plugin.cardid.org/)?

Comment: Já sim, instalei o plugin, mas não acontece nada. Mas valeu pela dica, vou ver a outra opção, inte!